# How to fix invisible value for php variable inside input field

Tags: php

I'm trying to display the users nickname into a html form input text field. It was working, but now quit showing up randomly. There is data in the database for the user. The fields are just blank and show nothing. I have plenty other fields working, but this does not and idk why. Feel free to edit the title I did not know how to word it.

When I try to implode the $nickname

```
$string_nickname = implode(',', $nickname);
```

I get the error

> Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Client-Projects\Crossfire\CoinSubmission.php on line
>   26

So, I tried parsing it to just a string since it's not an array, like..

```
$string_nickname = $nickname['nickname'];
```

But when I do this the field in the form is just completely blank and it gives no error.

Here is the input field where I insert nickname.

```
<label>NICKNAME:</label>
  <input type="text" name="nickname" id="nickname" value="<?php echo $string_nickname; ?>" readonly>
```

and where I select and set nickname.

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT adminlogin.nickname FROM adminlogin INNER JOIN coinsub ON coinsub.profileid=adminlogin.profileid") or die(mysqli_error($con));
$nickname = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$string_nickname = implode(',', $nickname);
```

Please let me know if you need anymore info.

Comment: Are you trying to show all the nicknames or a particular nickname? I take it that the nickname you are trying to put into your form field is the current user. You might need a Where clause in your query to pull out the right user. It should return just one record in most cases.

Comment: @nocturns2 The OP is imploding the nicknames with a comma. So it looks like they want to get all the nicknames.

Comment: I was trying to clarify the question. Trying to figure out why the OP wants to put an array into the input field. But that's what they want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Do it with object orientated mysqli

```php
$arr = array();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  $arr[] = $row['nickname'];
}
$string_nickname = implode(',', $arr);
```

You are fetching one value, I think you need more than one. Just create a new array, push to it and you are done. Even if you have one value in the database, this works The above array contains all the nicknames we get from the database. Once you implode them, they are like

```
nickname1, nickname2, nickname3, nicknamen
```

So your whole code becomes something like this

```php
$result = $con->query("SELECT adminlogin.nickname FROM adminlogin INNER JOIN coinsub ON coinsub.profileid=adminlogin.profileid") or die(mysqli_error($con));
$arr = array();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  $arr[] = $row['nickname'];
}
$string_nickname = implode(',', $arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implode try this :

```
$string_nickname = implode(', ', (array)$nickname);
```

For select mysqli try this :

```
$selectquery = $con->prepare("SELECT adminlogin.nickname FROM adminlogin 
                              LEFT JOIN coinsub ON coinsub.profileid=adminlogin.profileid");
$selectquery->execute(); 
$result = $selectquery->get_result(); 
$user = $result->fetch_assoc();
$nickname = $user['nickname'];
```

You can also use while statement as follow :

```
while($user=$result->fetch_assoc()){

echo $user['nickname'];

}
```

Comment: _you are getting the error because nickname is not an array_ Why? `mysqli_fetch_assoc` returns an associative array. Every time. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/apis-php/en/apis-php-mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.html

Comment: i never said that you are an idiot and never tried to school you. I just asked that why are you casting the type array to a variable that is always an array. Kindly answer that question or if you don’t want to, ignore it. We are all here to learn and I’m not trying to teach anyone.

Answer (score 0):

```
$string_nickname = '';
if(!empty($nickname)){
$string_nickname = implode(',', $nickname);
}
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, code only answers are generally regarded as lo-quality. Providing some more description and context on why will improve the quality of this answer. Thanks.